Decidability in Natural Numbers with a Combined Function
It is well known that there is no algorithm to determine whether a given first-order sentence is true in the structure of natural numbers with both addition and multiplication. In contrast, Presburger arithmetic, which involves natural numbers with addition but without multiplication, is decidable. Now, consider this function which combines addition and multiplication:
$$ a \oplus b \mapsto (a + b)^2 $$
If we consider the structure of natural numbers with just this function, is there an algorithm that can determine whether a first-order sentence is true in this structure or not?

Hello. Is this homework? If so, could you say what you've tried so far and what your thoughts are? If you're stuck, here's a hint: you should think about how you could make use of either of your first two sentences to solve this problem. I won't say which, but one of them leads into a nice way to resolve this question!

What is "the structure of natural numbers with just this function"? What are the axioms?

@NaïmFavier, it seems to me that OP means "the complete theory of the structure $(\Bbb N, \oplus)$", in the same way that Presburger arithmetic is "the complete theory of $(\Bbb N, +, 0, 1)$" (though it's not usually defined like that).

@NaïmFavier The kind of decision problem the OP has in mind is made clear in the first sentence: given a sentence, is it true in this structure? I don't understand the downvotes.

Apologies, I misunderstood the question.

Let's make some observations about definability in the structure $(\mathbb{N},\oplus)$. I'll tell you what's definable, and you try to find a definition (the definitions are hidden in the spoiler blocks).

$0$ is definable


 $0$ is the unique element $x$ satisfying $x\oplus x = x$.


Using $0$, the squaring function is definable.


 $x^2$ is $0\oplus x$.


Using the squaring function, addition is definable.


 $x+y$ is the unique element $z$ satisfying $x\oplus y = z^2$.


Using the squaring function and addition, multiplication is definable.


 $xy$ is the unique element $z$ satisfying $x\oplus y = x^2 + y^2 + z + z$.

Now that we can see that addition and multiplication are both definable, it is clear that the complete theory of $(\mathbb{N},\oplus)$ is undecidable.
